# Loop over registered results with test

Tags: loops, ansible

In my playbook a task get a registered results. I would like to iterate in a loop the tasks `Retrieve list of volumes to eradicate`, but with the test and the specific value I'm looking for, I can't find the right syntax.

```yaml
---
- name: Array management
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: yes
  any_errors_fatal: true
  max_fail_percentage: 0

  vars_files:
    - vars/{{ env }}.yml

  tasks:
    - name: Gather volume and hosts info from array
      purestorage.flasharray.purefa_info:
        gather_subset:
          - hosts
        fa_url: "{{ item.fa_url }}"
        api_token: "{{ item.api_token }}"
      register: array_info
      with_items:
        - { fa_url: "{{ src_fa_url }}" , api_token: "{{ src_fa_api_token }}" }
        - { fa_url: "{{ tgt_fa_url }}" , api_token: "{{ tgt_fa_api_token }}" }


    - name: Retrieve list of volumes to eradicate 1
      set_fact:
          volumes_list: "{{ volumes_list | default([]) }} + {{ array_info.results[0].purefa_info.hosts[item].volumes | map(attribute='volume') | list }}"
      when:  array_info.results[0].purefa_info.hosts[item] is defined
      with_items: "{{ src_host_name }}"

    - name: Retrieve list of volumes to eradicate 2
      set_fact:
          volumes_list2: "{{ volumes_list2 | default([]) }} + {{ array_info.results[1].purefa_info.hosts[item].volumes | map(attribute='volume') | list }}"
      when:  array_info.results[1].purefa_info.hosts[item] is defined
      with_items: "{{ src_host_name }}"
```

If I can group the tasks `Retrieve list of volumes to eradicate` in a loop because I don't know how many iteration I can have in results.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to be sure without an example data to test against (please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](/help/mcve)) but from the bits in you question, you should be able to get the information you are looking for with a single jinja2 expression (might have to adapt a bit because of lack of possible test on my side):

```
"{{ array_info.results | map(attribute='purefa_info`) 
| map('dict2items', 'host', 'host_info') 
| selectattr('host', 'in', src_host_name) 
| map(attribute='host_info.volumes') | flatten 
| map(attribute='volume') }}"
```

Once you have tuned this expression to your actual data, you can use it as is in a `loop` stanza or set it as a variable in a `vars` section at play or task level. Using `set_fact` will also work but is not needed in that case.